# DirectX Demo does not draw anything on screen

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am learning DirectX 11 right now, and was trying out one of the demos from the book "Beginning DirectX 11 programming". I followed the books guidelines to make a base class that handles window creation and destruction(including d3d11 setup). All other demos are based on this class. So I was writing the Triangle demo, where the aim is to draw a 2d triangle. Here is the implementation of the Triangle class:

```
#include "Triangle.h"


Triangle::Triangle(void): mVertexShader(0), mPixelShader(0), mInputLayout(0), mVertexBuffer(0)
{
}


Triangle::~Triangle(void)
{
}

void Triangle::Update(float deltaTime){

}

void Triangle::UnloadContent(){
    if(mVertexShader)
        mVertexShader->Release();

    if(mPixelShader)
        mPixelShader->Release();

    if(mInputLayout)
        mInputLayout->Release();

    if(mVertexBuffer)
        mVertexBuffer->Release();

    mVertexBuffer = 0;
    mPixelShader = 0;
    mVertexShader = 0;
    mInputLayout = 0;
}

bool Triangle::LoadContent(){
    //Load Vertex Shader and make it active
    ID3DBlob* vsBlob = 0;

    if(!CompileShader(L"shaders.fx", "VS_Main", "vs_4_0", &vsBlob)){
        MessageBox(0, L"Error Loading Vertex Shader", L"Compile Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    HRESULT hr;
    if(FAILED(hr = mDevice->CreateVertexShader(vsBlob->GetBufferPointer(), vsBlob->GetBufferSize(), 0, &mVertexShader))){
        if(vsBlob)
            vsBlob->Release();

        return false;
    }

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexLayout[] = {
        {
            "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0
        }
    };

    unsigned int layoutSize = ARRAYSIZE(vertexLayout);

    if(FAILED(mDevice->CreateInputLayout(
            vertexLayout,
            layoutSize,
            vsBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
            vsBlob->GetBufferSize(),
            &mInputLayout
        ))){
            vsBlob->Release();
            return false;
    }

    vsBlob->Release();

    ID3DBlob* psBlob = 0;

    if(!CompileShader(L"shaders.fx", "PS_Main", "ps_4_0", &psBlob)){
        MessageBox(0, L"Error Loading Pixel Shader", L"Compile Error", MB_OK);

        if(psBlob)
            psBlob->Release();

        return false;
    }

    if(FAILED(mDevice->CreatePixelShader(
            psBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
            psBlob->GetBufferSize(),
            0,
            &mPixelShader
        ))){
            psBlob->Release();
            return false;
    }

    psBlob->Release();


    //vertex buffer creation
    VertexPos vertices[] =
    {
        XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
        XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
        XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f )
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexDesc, sizeof(vertexDesc));

    vertexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexPos) * 3;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresourceData;
    ZeroMemory(&subresourceData, sizeof(subresourceData));
    subresourceData.pSysMem = vertices;

    if(FAILED(mDevice->CreateBuffer(
            &vertexDesc,
            &subresourceData,
            &mVertexBuffer
        ))){
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Triangle::CompileShader(wchar_t* filePath, char* entry, char* shaderModel, ID3DBlob** buffer){
    DWORD shaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;

#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
    shaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

    ID3DBlob* errorBuffer = 0;
    HRESULT result;

    result = D3DX11CompileFromFileW(
            filePath,
            0,0,
            entry,
            shaderModel,
            shaderFlags,
            0,0,
            buffer,
            &errorBuffer,
            0
        );

    if(FAILED(result)){
        if(errorBuffer != 0){
            OutputDebugStringA((char*) errorBuffer->GetBufferPointer());
            errorBuffer->Release();
        }
        return false;
    }
    if(errorBuffer)
        errorBuffer->Release();

    return true;
}


void Triangle::Render(){
    float clearColor[4] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.25f, 1.0f };
    mDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(mRenderTarget, clearColor);

    unsigned int stride = sizeof(VertexPos);
    unsigned int offset = 0;

    mDeviceContext->IASetInputLayout(mInputLayout);
    mDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    mDeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    mDeviceContext->VSSetShader(mVertexShader, 0, 0);
    mDeviceContext->PSSetShader(mPixelShader, 0, 0);
    mDeviceContext->Draw(3, 0);

    mSwapChain->Present(0, 0);

}
```

Now when I run this the screen clears up and takes the color i specify, but nothing is drawn on the screen. Just to be sure I just compiled the source code provided by the book and it works just fine. The shaders used are also the same. My computer does support directx 11. Most of the names are self-explanatory i think, but you can ask me if it is confusing. I've tested my framework with other demos and it works fine. I can't seem to find the error in my code.

Comment: I did a quick glance and your input layout is specifying the position data as DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT (float4) where as your vertex array passes position as float3. This may cause issues I can't recall though.  

So either make the array XMFLOAT4 or change the layout and shader code so appropriately. (quickest would be to swap to XMFLOAT4 and (a,b,c,1)

Shader code might be needed to identify the real issue though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Positions need to be encoded either in standard Euclidean space coordinates, a 3-tuple - or - passed in 4D homogenous coordinates which have the 4th component set to 1 (a 4-tuple)(since they're points). When you pass in your input element description, the layout of your vertex data, you set `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` in:

```
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexLayout[] = 
{
    {
         "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0
    }
};
```

But are only passing in 3D vertices:

```
VertexPos vertices[] =
    {
        XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
        XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
        XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f )
    };
```

One might guess at first that your w coordinate gets initialized to 0 and that it somehow messes up transforms in the vertex shader, but what happens is inherent to the linear memory layout and how you promised the GPU it would get its data. You said it is getting a 32-bit 4-tuple and it is only getting 32-bit 3-tuples. Now, since they're adjacent, they seem to get pumped into wrong slots *on first glance*. However, breaking a type on the boundary is strictly forbidden by HLSL, so it just dies.

**How to fix it?**

Simple, change to `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` and adjust your HLSL code to add the fourth component of points and set it to 1.0 like float4(pos, 1.0) and multiply it with the world, view, projection matrix you've constructed on the CPU, also, do remember HLSL is column-major while C++ is row-major. That means you need to transpose everything that goes over to HLSL in order for the calculations to make sense.

Happy coding.